# Weka Metacost - How to view the total cost

Tags: weka

I am using the Metacost function in Weka. I would like to view the total cost of the classifier. Could someone please tell me how to view the total cost? I am using the Weka GUI explorer.

I have tried enabling the cost sensitive evaluation option in the 'more option' part in the classify tab. However, since I have to enter the cost matrix twice then (once in the metacost and once in the more options part), would the system return the total cost for metacost or the cost sensitive classifier ? I am a bit confused by it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the cost matrix you supply for the classifier simply informs Weka how the classifier should be built.  It will not affect the evaluation of the classifier.  If you do want to evaluate the classifier's performance under the same cost structure, you of course would need to supply the cost matrix for cost sensitive evaluation.

In the procedure you describe, the output total cost would be from the cost sensitive evaluation.